# What was the real name of the painter who made the Christ Pantocrator of Sant Climent de Taüll Church?

Tags: art

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Ta%C3%BCll) he's named as the "Master of Tahull", and also on other sites that I've consulted.

Is there a record of his real name?

Comment: If all sites refer to him as *The Master of Taüll* with no name mentioned, we probably have to assume that this is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The [Old Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Master) were a category of artists who worked before 1800.  There are quite a few of these master artists who are unknown today. Some examples are mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Master#Anonymous_artists):

> Artists, most often from early periods, whose hand
>   has been identified by art historians, but to whom no identity can be
>   confidently attached, are often given names by art historians such as
>   *Master E.S.* (from his monogram), *Master of Flémalle* (from a previous
>   location of a work), *Master of Mary of Burgundy* (from a patron),
>   *Master of Latin 757* (from the shelf mark of a manuscript he
>   illuminated), *Master of the Brunswick Diptych* or *Master of Schloss
>   Lichtenstein*.

So it is not uncommon for an artist to be unknown and referred to by a title of a work they did or a location central to their works.

The relevant wiki entry for the [Master of Taüll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Ta%C3%BCll) gives no hint to any possible identity. The book [The Art of Medieval Spain, A.D. 500-1200](https://books.google.com/books?id=WdXQnaME1gMC&pg=PA195&dq=Master%20of%20Saint%20Climent&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU55qfgPfnAhXdPH0KHVUgDiMQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=Master%20of%20Saint%20Climent&f=false) By Jerrilynn D. Dodds lists this individual as the *Master of Sant Climent*, for his primary mural in the apse of the church in Taüll. A discussion (pp. 194-5) compares this artist with another unknown, the *Master of Santa Maria in Taüll*, which illustrates how common unknown artists are.